# Congratulations to Asaf

Tags: discussion, specific-user

Asaf Karagila has become the first to be on MSE for 1000 consecutive days. There is even a movie, *Asaf of the Thousand Days*, with Richard Burton, and Genevieve Bujold playing Asaf.

EDIT. The Guide For the Perplexed: Asaf is a male person living in Israel. He finished at Ben Gurion and is now at Hebrew University of Jerusalem. The movie took some liberties, for example, Bujold is French Canadian.

P.S.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_of_the_Thousand_Days
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guide_for_the_Perplexed

Comment: Do we need to collect some money to get him into rehab?

Comment: I like the rehab idea.

Comment: How did you know that? The information seems to be only visible to the user himself. Unless his account has been hacked by you?

Comment: @Tim: The second line of my answer may provide a hint about that.

Comment: Bring the money to asaf

Comment: If you knew of this movie as much as I did, and if you don't have time to go through Bujold's filmography, [it's here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064030/).

Comment: @Asaf: Wouldn't you rather celebrate with a [couple of these](http://www.spreewaldhof.net/inhalt.php?navh=produkte&navu=shop_gurken&navs=shop_gurken_get-one&seite=produktDetail&produkt=017&sprache=en)?  Congrats!  I guess...

Comment: Congrats, Asaf! Are you considering taking a day off in order to celebrate?

Comment: I think BG Univ andd HUJ should be listed as financial sponsors of MSE. ;-)

Comment: Congrats, Asaf! Will, how do we know that he is the *first* to be on MSE for 1000 consecutive days?

Comment: @P.. MSE has not existed for much more than that. One can presumably eliminate the other [fanatics](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/55/fanatic?userid=622) one-by-one by visiting their profiles.

Comment: @WillieWong: For all I know [Qiaochu](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan?tab=reputation) may have beaten [him](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila?tab=reputation).

Comment: @P.. certainly not. Qiaochu has visited 1002 days total. 87 of which is the most recent consecutive streak. Which means that before then the longest possible streak Qiaochu could've amassed is 915 days, which is a bit short of 1000.

Comment: OK, I see. Again congratulations to @AsafKaragila!

Comment: @Arthur: Not until June, sadly.

Comment: This is my surprised face: :-|

Comment: @MJD: Why surprised?

Comment: It's a joke. If I were *actually* surprised, my face would look like this: 8-o.

Comment: This thread is a 1,000 days old now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  could be. I probably check the site every day myself, I just don't bother with questions any more unless they fit one of the topics I've kept an interest in.

Comment: Well, certainly, because I've hit 2000 today.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, I did not put that together, and needed your expert guidance

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Thanks Will.
*(That was not what I had in mind when I told you about that)*

I suppose a screenshot would be appropriate...

> $\phantom{\dfrac12}$
>   $\hspace{110pt}$[image: I suppose a screenshot is appropriate here]
>   ${}$

Comment: Congratulations! I didn't know this is worth celebration, or I would have not skipped one days or two in the past which broke the continuum.

Comment: Just one more evidence you are the king of all existence, I guess. Enjoy the celebration.

Comment: What is your mother tongue, Asaf?

Comment: @Georges: Hebrew.

Comment: So, you're springing for arak on this most joyous occasion?

Comment: @J.M.: No, it's too hot for arak. (When it's hot arak has this awful aftertaste that you just can't get rid of.) until the heat breaks up in a couple of days I'll stick with beer (with the occasional shot of arak).

Comment: Dear Asaf, I asked because your command of English is amazing: how did you learn to write that foreign language so well?

Comment: @Georges: I began using the internet when I was 12, so I ran into English as an active user quite soon. But looking at things I wrote 12 years ago (I was 16) or so I feel bad for myself. At the age of 17 I decided to try and write proper English (that is no "ppl" and "thx" and keep capitalization), and as luck would have it, when I was 19 I got to write in a music e-zine, and the editor hired a guy that analyzed our writing styles and gave us tips how to write properly. Since then I tried my best to improve my English more and more.

Comment: Dear Asaf, thanks for answering these inappropriately personal questions. My lame excuse is that I am a language freak, impressed by the outstanding quality of your English , especially when  contrasted  with  the er... not quite stellar performance of some native speakers on this site. Anyway, I can only reiterate my sincere admiration for your linguistic performance.

Comment: @Georges: Thank you very much for the compliments!

Comment: I see, arak is anise flavored. I never liked fennel or anise. Not your problem, granted.

Comment: @Will: Many folks in Israel are not fans of anise either and dislike arak. I too hated it until I was 23 and worked for a short period as a cook in a local pub, where they rekindled my love for the drink.

Comment: @J.M. Although a little late for the celebration, but I just got my new Unicomp keyboard, so that's a nice way to celebrate: make it fun to write longer answers!

Comment: Just to say you Congratulations Asaf. :-)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Now I know that there is not a platinum version for the "Fanatic" badge.

Comment: Did you also visited "meta site" 1000 consecutive days?

Comment: @Gaston: No, I only started participating on meta when I was a somewhat more established member of the site. From my meta site profile at this moment: "visited  894 days, 638 consecutive".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wow... you will break up your record also in meta.

Comment: @Gaston: Who knows.

Comment: Stumbled over this, aimlessly browsing meta, and now must know if the line is still uninterupted.

Comment: @quid, 1174 days.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this record should have more upvotes then the point-based ones.

Comment: @quid: Perhaps. I generally dislike congratulatory threads. Last week, in the first week of the semester I told one of the groups I TA about MSE and I told them that even the heroin addicts that live in my neighborhood would say "Dude. You gotta get treatment for that addiction" about this site.... :-)

Comment: In general I do not like these threads that much either, but this one is special. And, good quote!

Comment: @quid: I agree this is a different thread than the rest of them.

Comment: @Gastón: In two hours it'll be 1000 straight on meta too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila nice, finally you got it, congrats!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is the line still uninterupted? If so, you will reach 2000 soon, won't you?

Comment: @wythagoras: Yeah, roughly in two weeks.

Comment: @wythagoras: And we're here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Congratulations. Would you mind if I mention it in the "In Praise of Math.SE and its users" chatroom? (a chat message is technically not a post)

Comment: @wythagoras: Martin already mentioned it.