# Consecutive visiting days more than 100

Tags: discussion, badges

consecutive visiting days for 100 days will reward a gold badge.

Just to make sure that: consecutive visiting days for $x$ days, more than 100 days, say will some $x>100$, there is another badge on the $x$th day?

Comment: No badge, as far as I know. But you might get [honorable mention on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/congratulations-to-asaf).

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY I think that list in you comment basically answers the question, so you could post it as an answer. (Perhaps with the addition that Enthusiast and Fanatic are the only two badges of this type on that list.)

Comment: You should feel free to award yourself a special secret badge whose existence is known only to yourself.  This badge will be just as legitimate and just as valuable as a badge awarded by the SE software would have been.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such badge as of now.
(It is conceivable, but seems highly unlikely, that such a badge might be created in the future and applied retroactively.)

Related threads [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/congratulations-to-asaf) and [on metaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile).